# npm package using @types/meteor cannot find module meteor/meteor

Tags: typescript, meteor, npm

I have published an npm package (meteor-model) that has a dependency on @types/meteor.
The project itself works fine and

```
import Meteor from 'meteor/meteor'
```

correctly resolves to

```
node_modules/@types/meteor
```

However, it does not work when I install this package in another project:

```
Cannot find module 'meteor/meteor'
```

thrown in

```
node_modules\meteor-model\dist\MeteorModelDecorators.js:38:16
```

The repo is here: https://github.com/navio-xyz/meteor-model

Comment: silly question but... is meteor initialised in the second project ?

Answer (score 6):

Now you can just use the following command to install meteor types:

```sh
meteor npm install @types/meteor --save
```

Comment: Fixed my issue. Why this isn't in the doc ?

Answer (score 3):

You simply cannot use 'meteor/*' package to import any module, because there is no meteor package system. If you want to use Meteor or Mongo etc., you can just use it as global variable directly. 
To enable the type check for such global variables, here is what to do:

1. install @types/meteor package using

```sh
npm install --save-dev @types/meteor
```

2. add types into your compilerOptions in your tsconfig.json file like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     ...
     "types": [
       "meteor"
     ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need to install the `meteor` package. Your library cannot `import` from there without that dependency.

```
npm install meteor --save
```

`@types/*` is just the definition, so TypeScript knows how to typecheck. You still need the implementation.

Comment: It's a meteor project. There is no npm meteor package. www.meteor.com